# ARM v5 shared library (ftd2xx) on ARM v7 platform - hard vs soft float issue

Tags: architecture, arm, backwards-compatibility, beagleboard

I need to run a program that uses ftd2xx on my BeagleBoard xM rev C running Ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to use the ARM library libftd2xx.so provided [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm). libFTDI is not an option.

The difference that I noticed comes from running `readelf -hA` on libftd2xx.so vs other libraries on the BeagleBoard that work. The arch-specific section gives OS name as "ARM926EF-S" for ftd2xx instead of "7-A" for other libraries and CPU_arch as "v5TEJ" instead of "v7".

I'm assuming this means that the library is meant for the ARM v5 instruction set, and the BeagleBoard is running ARM v7. Is there some way to get ftd2xx to work?

Edit: I've been told ARM7 is backward compatible with ARM5, but that does not solve my problem.

Another thing to note is that running `ldd libftd2xx.so` on the BeagleBoard does not list the dependencies, but prints out `not a dynamic executable`, whereas it works on other libraries.

EDIT 2:

The issue seems to be with a soft vs hard float ABI. I have a gnueabihf image on the BeagleBoard xM. When I try to compile an example program with the static libftd2xx.a, I get many of these:

`/usr/bin/ld: error: static_link_uses VFP register arguments, libftd2xx.a(file.o) does not

/usr/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file libftd2xx.a(file.o)`

If I try to compile with `mfloat-abi=soft` or `mfloatabi=softfp`, I get

`In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,

           from main.c:12:

/usr/include/features.h:324:26 fatal error: bits/predef.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated`

I also tried to cross compile with `arm-linux-gnueabi` instead of `arm-linux-gnueabihf`, but the resulting program does not execute on the BeagleBoard. Is there anything I can do or is it impossible?

--------- SOLUTION ----------------

After some trouble, FTDI provided me with a hard float version of their library which works. I am providing it here after many people have individually requested it:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/hayk-public/arm926-hf.zip

Comment: What is it that's not working exactly? where do you run `ldd`, on host? try `readelf |grep Shared`. You may need an ldd with arm support or something. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150000/cross-compiler-ldd) You should try to dig more for information like using strac, checking logs etc. Did you read the README from ftdi site?

Comment: I run `ldd` on the BeagleBoard, so it should already by an ARM version (it works on the ARM libraries in /usr/lib). I read the readme and contacted FTDI to no avail. I've looked at strace, but I don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: paste strace to somewhere then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v5TEJ is a subset of the v7-A instruction set.

The code may run a bit slower and may be a bit larger than required, but it should nonetheless work without crashing due to illegal instructions or so. With very few exceptions ARM  code is backward compatible to previous instruction sets.

If the code does not work on your platform it is very likely something else like missing access rights to the USB subsystem or so.

Comment: Running ldd on the binary returns w/ no output. strace shows that it is looking for the library, which it eventually finds. Then, it has a few calls to lseek and eventually exits with code 1. If it helps, I can update my answer with the full output.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the fact that `ldd libftd2xx.so` does not print out dependencies, which in my mind rules out permission issues.

Answer (score 2):

Please see my [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/utwVw9Bb) output for `strace` and `ldd` on an ARM926 processor.  The binaries inside [libftd2xx1.1.12](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/libftd2xx1.1.12.tar.gz) have multiple processors.  Ensure you are using `release/build/arm926`.  I can run the `statictest` binary on an ARM926 CPU, with eglibc and Linux 2.6.36.

From the `ldd` output, the following libraries are required.

- `libdl.so.2` - dynamic loading.
- `librt.so.1` - real-time library
- `libpthread.so.0` - pthreads
- `libgcc_s.so.1` - gcc helpers.
- `libc.so.6` - eglibc library
- `ld-linux.so.3` - the Linux shared library loader.

A functional `ldd` is not needed and the following command should display libraries,

```
LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 LD_WARN=yes LD_BIND_NOW=yes LD_VERBOSE=yes \
 /lib/ld-linux.so.3 ./libftd2xx.so.1.1.12
```

Verify that the `statictest` binary work.  If so, try to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the `release/build/arm926/libftd2xx.so.1.1.12` location.  From the `strace` output, the paths `/lib/tls/v5l` and `/lib/tls` are preferred over `/lib`.  All of the libraries listed above should be in `/lib`.  You can try to `ln` (hard link) them to that location.  Also, from the `strace` output, the `/proc/bus/usb` filesystem should be mounted.  This is a kernel config option.  `/sys/bus/usb/devices` is used extensively to find devices; it is unlikely that this is missing on your Ubuntu 12.04 ARM Linux.  There is also a `libd2xx_table.so` which is most likely used to find non-standard USB descriptors.

Finally, it would be helpful to be more descriptive of the problem.  You try to run some program and there is no output?  Or you run the program and it has an exception?  If the `statictest` **ARM** binary fails to run, then your original assumption might be correct.  It is possible that the older 2.6.32 kernel (or ld-linux.so) finds `ARM926EJ-S` compatible but your newer Ubuntu 12.04 does not find it compatible.  In this case, use `man ld-linux` on a PC host to see the `ld-linux.so` environment variables.  Specifically, `LD_DEBUG` and `LD_ASSUME_KERNEL` may be helpful to coax the loader to load the binaries.

Comment: Thanks for the help - the static test does not run, see my edit 2. It looks like a hard vs soft float issue - anything I can do?

Comment: You can statically link everything with `softfp` and the `arm-linux-gnueabi` tools.  Alternatively, you can install the other shared libraries (listed above in something like `/opt/lib/softfp`) from the `arm-linux-gnueabi` tools and set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to them.  `hard-float` versus `soft` makes perfect sense.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand, can you clarify what I should try? If I cross-compile statictest with `arm-linux-gnueabi`, the program does not execute on the BeagleBoard.

Comment: The `statictest` is not really static.   Only the `libftd2xx.a` is used, which is static.  The above libraries are dynamically link.  Your `arm-linux-gnueabi` may come with a `populate` script.  This will look for and copy shared libraries to run an executable. Either using `chroot` or setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to make sure that the non-hardfp libraries are found.  `chroot` might be better; you can setup a mini-filesystem and use it with `chroot`.  I do this with `klibc` for instance.