# Getting started with libftdi

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, beagleboard, ftdi

I want to build a program that communicate with ftdi device from beagleboard XM EzSDK 6.0 board. FTDI provides pre-compiled D2XX library for arm Linux Kernel version 2.6.32. But EzSDK 6.0 uses Linux Kernel 3.3.7. So i downloaded opensource libftdi from http://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/download.php 
In the ReadMe, They tells

```
If you are building the release tar ball, just extract the source tar ball.

    cd libftdi
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr" ../
    make
    sudo make install
```

My query is when i follow above steps, it will create library for development environment (Ubuntu LTS 12.04),right? .
I want to run this program in ezsdk 6.0 board.   How to specify target in the cross compilation.   I am  new to Linux and i need getting started  information for this.

Comment: See [ArmV5 Shared library FTD2xx float issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306447/arm-v5-shared-library-ftd2xx-on-arm-v7-platform-hard-vs-soft-float-issue), which may have some information for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xtract the source tar ball.

```
tar xvjf libftdi1-1.0.tar.bz2
cd libftdi
mkdir build
cd build
```

//Source the /linux-devkit/environment-setup script to prepare to configure and build the plugins.

```
source <SDK INSTALL DIR>/linux-devkit/environment-setup
```

Then follow

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr" ../
make
make install
```

Thats all..