# Running an ELF file on a different ARM linux platform

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux, elf

I have an executable file from an embedded device running linux. The device is running on an ARMv5TE Intel PXA255. Since that platform is long obsolete, I would like to run the program on a more modern and cheap Atheros AR9331 running OpenWrt 12.09.
Following common sense and some info I found on the net, I thought that I could just `chmod +X prog1` the file and then run it. Unfortunately, doing that does nothing... The program is not recognized: at the prompt, if I write the first characters and press tab nothing happens, if I write the file name and press enter I get `/bin/ash: prog1: not found`, and of course if I write `./prog1` I get this error:
`./prog1: line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")`

more info:

-I verified that the header is 0x7F 'E' 'L' 'F'

-The program seems to decompile correctly on IDA

Am I getting these errors because the platforms are too different?
What am I doing wrong/what can I do to run this program? I don't have sources.

Comment: ELF is a container format.  It does not mean that the instruction set specifics, ABI, or shared library dependencies are necessarily compatible.  As a starting point you could use tools like readelf or objdump to examine this file in comparison to sample executables from the new system.

Comment: The first check would be to run [file](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) on your old binary and compare its output with any binary on OpenWrt.

Comment: The older binary will be compiled with a different ABI.  For instance soft vs hard float, etc.  See [ArmV5 FTD2xx on ArmV7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306447/arm-v5-shared-library-ftd2xx-on-arm-v7-platform-hard-vs-soft-float-issue).

Comment: Thank you @Chris, you made it extremely clear using 3 words, while I got the exact opposite impression while reading the wikipedia article on ELF.
The `file` command returns, for the original program:
`prog1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, stripped`
and for an OpenWrt program:
`opkg: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), corrupted section header size`.

Comment: So I think I'm seeing the problem now, and I guess that I will not be able to run that program without recompiling it... Am I right?

Comment: Yes, a lot of routers are MIPS not ARM.  Needless to say that is not going to work.